# Re-open a file in binary mode with Python

Tags: python, file-io

Say I have a file object which was opened in mode 'r' (such as from the default `open()` call), but I need to read it in binary mode ('rb').

Is there a way to change the mode directly, or do I need to make a new file object using something like `open(foo.name, 'rb')` (assuming my file object is named `foo`)?

**EDIT**: Ideally, the solution to this problem should be platform-independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2 you'll have to open a new file object; you cannot change the file mode on an already-opened file.

You can do so with the previous file object:

```
def reopen_binary(fobj):
    mode = fobj.mode
    if 'b' not in mode:
        mode += 'b'
    return open(fobj.name, mode)  # encoding and newline options don't apply
```

In Python 3 you can access the underlying [buffered I/O file object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase), via the [`TextIOBase.buffer` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.buffer):

```
raw_buffered = fobj.buffer
```

or reach all the way down to the [raw file object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), both are always binary:

```
raw = fobj.buffer.raw
```

The same hierarchy is available in Python 2 if you use the [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open).